# Could be possible to overload the method of a typename in a template?

Tags: c++

I will like to be able to detect when a function of a template param is called. Something like this:

```
struct Foo {
  int count = 0;
  void add(int amount) {
    count += amount;
  }
};

struct Baz {
  int baz;
};

template <typename Data> struct Bar {
  Data data;

  // I know this syntax is wrong but it kind of explains what I want to do
  void Data::add(int amount) {
    printf("add was called");
    Data::add(amount);
  }
};

Bar<Foo> bar;
bar.data.add(10); // add was called

Bar<Baz> baz;
bar.data.add(5); // error! since add is not present in Baz
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot hook an arbitrary method of an arbitrary class from outside of that class.

Comment: Nope, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. The closest to this would be when the original class method is virtual, in which case you "detect" if it's called by overriding it in a subclass. But what is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not about how to "detect" that the method gets called, but the original problem to which the solution you believe is to detect that the method gets called? Perhaps if the original problem is explained a completely different solution will be possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik just curiosity

Comment: `template<typename Data> struct Bar { struct intercept : Data { void add(int amount) { printf("added"); Data::add(amount); } } data; };`